# How to enable or disable crons in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cron, crontab, magento-cron

I checked in cron_schedule table, cron are disabled.
I want to enable or disable crons.
How can I do that?

Comment: do you want to set CRON job ?

Comment: actually I'm working on existing site, on staging all crons are disabled I just want to start them..

Comment: just run cron:run command to start cron

Comment: @magefms can this runs crons by schedule?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#config-cli-cron-group-run

Comment: yeah kindly check link

Comment: yes checking.. thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
php bin/magento cron:install
```

Above command will Generates and installs crontab for current user

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: for disable CRON you can use `cron:remove`.

Comment: Ok. I also ran the cron:run command.. it set the schedule in cron_schedule table.. but it not runs automatically?

Comment: have you ran `cron:install` ? as per my screen shot.

Comment: yes.. it shows me error : Error during saving of crontab: You are not allowed to use this program (crontab)

Comment: Are you logged in as root ?

Comment: The screenshot is outdated with version 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

**Add the Magento crontab**

> php bin/magento cron:install

**Remove the Magento crontab**

You should remove the Magento crontab only before uninstalling the Magento application.

> bin/magento cron:remove

**Run cron from the command line**

> bin/magento cron:run [--group=""]

For more detail see [Magento cron devDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

I hope it helps!

Comment: I ran bin/magento cron:run [--group=""] command.. record added into cron_schedule table.. but crons not running automatically..

Comment: In your cron file add below code to debug log.

Comment: `$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info('Your text message');`

Comment: On our staging instance, there is read only file system. so I can not copy code directly their. deployment process is very big.. sorry but is there any another way to check on staging instance.. from admin or CLI commands?

Comment: In `cron_schedule` table have you checked cron is executed? in execute column?

Comment: Yes.. cron scheduled for every minute.. but it's status is still pending..

Comment: Ok there is an issue in cron pending. do the following :

Empty the `cron_schedule` table & then run a command `bin/magento cron:run` and check in table

Comment: Ok checking....

Comment: Cleared the table and run the cron:run command.. now there are 4 records of same cron with different schedule.. 1st runs by default.. another 3 are still pending.. it should run every minute.. but not running..

Comment: without print log, it is difficult to solve your problem.  so try to log in cron file & check.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
php bin/magento cron:install [--force]
```

Force rewrites existing Magento cron tab

View the crontab by running

```
crontab -l
```

Run the crontab by

```
bin/magento cron:run [--group="<cron group name>"]
```

Omit the group to run crontab for all groups

You must run cron twice. The first time to discover tasks to run and the second time to run the tasks themselves.

Once done check your cron_schedule table in database to check if cron jobs are scheduled

Comment: cron:install not working on our staging instance because of read only file system.. it shows error: Error during saving of crontab: You are not allowed to use this program (crontab)

Comment: So the Magento user don't have write access?