# M2 | Why we need to execute cron:run twice executing first time?

Tags: cron, crontab, magento-cron

I created a custom cron job and tested on local server, where it needs to run

> bin/magento cron:run

two times simultaneously and then that custom job is created and scheduled.

why is it like that ?

Comment: did you setup CRON job on local ?

Comment: I didn't set it from Stores->Settings->Configuration->Advanced->System, is it due to this? something missing..

Comment: if you set CRON, your module's cron job automatic get schedule you don't need to run cron manually.

Comment: Yes it runs automatically, but first time when we need to execute cron:run, at that time it needs to run twice the run command to get the job scheduled..

Comment: that what i am saying, after set CRON, you don't need to run cron:run. based on your configuration in module it will run please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275556/how-to-enable-or-disable-crons-in-magento-2/275557#275557

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because its made to work like this.

It's from Magento documentation

"You must run cron twice: the first time to discover tasks to run and the second time — to run the tasks themselves. The second cron run must occur on or after the scheduled_at time for every task"

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html