# how to run cron jobs automatically in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

i have to run all cron jobs automatically. i had used this one php bin/magento cron:run --group="captcha_delete_expired_images" to delete captcha images manually but it is not deleting the images.

so please help me out how to run cron jobs automatically

Comment: please check: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275556/how-to-enable-or-disable-crons-in-magento-2/275557#275557

Answer (score 1):

You have to add cronjobs from the server.

First, you have to write ***crontab -e*** as it will open crontab edited where you will write the cron.

*/15 * * * * php bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/log/magento.cron.log

after saving this you can check the added cron with ***crontab -l***