# magento 2 how to run indexer command command every 5 mins

Tags: magento2

magento 2 how to run indexer command command every 5 mins or is we have any backend option for run the indexer command in magento 2 ?
My problem is when change the status from disable to enable salable quantity not updated once run the indexer command it will updated so i need to run this command every 5 mins. magento  have any backend options for this?
What is the purpose of this cron scedule tab in backend

[image]

Comment: do you set CRON ?

Comment: No ,I need to know when run the core indexer cron

Comment: You need to set CRON, it will take care of all indexing.

Comment: please have a look : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275556/how-to-enable-or-disable-crons-in-magento-2/275557#275557

Comment: Okay, i have one doubt what is the what reason update and scedule status,I mean when change this status when will run this indexer

Comment: Update by Schedule : will work as per CRON
Update On Save : When you made any changes, they will get autmatic done

Comment: Yes i need to know Update by Schedule : will work as per CRON
Cron schedule time on  Update by Schedule,where i have to check this time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110850/discussion-between-pawan-and-kanidhaya).

Answer (score 0):

Please create php file and added to my scheduled tasks in my control panel.

```
<?php system('<path to php> <path to root>/bin/magento indexer:reindex') ?>
<?php system('<path to php> <path to root>/bin/magento cache:status') ?>
```

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: I have updated my question please check